# JS Create a method to indent text

Tags: javascript, jquery, indentation

I was trying to create a system for indent the text (code).
I have a div with attribute contenteditable set to true where your code can be written.

This is my code:

```
    function moveCaret(win, charCount) {
    var sel, range;
    if (win.getSelection) {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var textNode = sel.focusNode;
            var newOffset = sel.focusOffset + charCount;
            sel.collapse(textNode, Math.min(textNode.length, newOffset));
        }
    } else if ( (sel = win.document.selection) ) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.move("character", charCount);
            range.select();
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var edit = $('.edit');

    edit.on('keydown',function(e) {
        var e = e || window.event;
            charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if(charCode == 9) {
            moveCaret(window, 5);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

If I click in a text and press the TAB button, the cursor moves forward five positions.
The problem is that this does not work if inside the div there is no text, I would that would shift the cursor without text.

How can I fix?

Comment: Perhaps you have to insert the text then? Perhaps something like 5 `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this way but the code is not interpreted, then put in the div exactly five times: `&nbsp;`

This is the code:

```
function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
var sel, range, html;
if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode( document.createTextNode(text) );
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    document.selection.createRange().text = text;
}
}

var edit = $('.edit');

    edit.on('keydown',function(e) {
        var e = e || window.event;
            charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if(charCode == 9) {
            var indent = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            insertTextAtCursor(indent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```